# "duplicate key value violates unique constraint" in upsert in Postgres 14

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-14

I have a query that I've been successfully running since Postgres added upsert support, I believe that was 9.6:

```
INSERT INTO gitrefresh(projecttag, state, analysis_started, counter_requested, customer_id) 
VALUES('npm@randombytes', 'Q', NOW(), 1, 0) 
ON CONFLICT (projecttag) DO UPDATE SET state='Q';
```

Out of nowhere, I started getting this error, I'm on 14.5 now:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_projecttag"
DETAIL:  Key (projecttag)=(npm@randombytes) already exists.
```

In the server log there's almost the same:

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "idx_projecttag"
DETAIL:  Key (projecttag)=(npm@randombytes) already exists.
STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO gitrefresh(projecttag, state, analysis_started, counter_requested, customer_id) VALUES                 ('npm@randombytes',         'Q',    NOW(),             1,                0) ON CONFLICT (projecttag) DO UPDATE SET state='Q'
```

I don't understand what's going on, it's acting as if it didn't use the `ON CONFLICT` part.

The table in question:

```
 \d+ gitrefresh
+-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Column            | Type                        | Modifiers                                                | Storage  | Stats target | Description |
|-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------|
| projecttag        | text                        |                                                          | extended | <null>       | <null>      |
| state             | character(1)                |                                                          | extended | <null>       | <null>      |
| analysis_started  | timestamp without time zone |                                                          | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| analysis_ended    | timestamp without time zone |                                                          | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| counter_requested | integer                     |                                                          | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| customer_id       | integer                     |                                                          | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
| id                | integer                     |  not null default nextval('gitrefresh_id_seq'::regclass) | plain    | <null>       | <null>      |
+-------------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------------------------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
Indexes:
    "pk_gitrefresh" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "idx_projecttag" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (projecttag)
Has OIDs: no
```

Comment: It looks like your unique index is on projecttag and on conflict of projecttag you are trying to update the state which doesn't make sense. You might wanna include state in unique index. But it totally depends on your functionality. Since you already have projecttag = npm@randombytes, you will not allowed to add it again.

Comment: Check with `\d gitrefresh` (and please update the question with the output) that the table has the unique constraints that you expect (and the migration from previous version to 14 did not change anything). Also check if the table has triggers.

Comment: @Kaushalpanchal it makes perfect sense.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ I've added the table definition. I can't add state to the index, the whole goal of this table is to map projectid to its state, there needs to be only one row for every projectid.

Comment: My guess is that it may be some corruption in the index or table, especially since the type is text. Check Postgres docs about upgrades and related issues. Did you do any OS upgrade recently? If I remember well, there was a related issue with OS upgrades and collations/locales. See: https://www.crunchydata.com/blog/glibc-collations-and-data-corruption

Comment: Yes, the database was moved to RHEL8-based OS 2 months ago, that could be it, libc version is 2.28 indeed. REINDEX isn't working though, it claims there is a duplicate row, when I do SELECT - there's only one row with that value. Does it mean the table got broken too, somehow?

Comment: a VACUUM FULL followed by REINDEX has fixed things. Thank you, I'll format it as an answer when I fix the problem

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ will you want to add the answer yourself? I don't want to steal your karma

Comment: Please do write an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [found by user ypercubeᵀᴹ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/320683/duplicate-key-value-violates-unique-constraint-in-upsert-in-postgres-14#comment625496_320683), the problem was with a corrupted index. This happens when upgrading your operating system to one with glibc 2.28 - such as Ubuntu 18.04, Debian 10 or CentOS/RHEL 8.

This query will find the indices possibly affected by the problem:

```
SELECT indrelid::regclass::text, indexrelid::regclass::text, collname, pg_get_indexdef(indexrelid)
FROM (SELECT indexrelid, indrelid, indcollation[i] coll FROM pg_index, generate_subscripts(indcollation, 1) g(i)) s
 JOIN pg_collation c ON coll=c.oid
WHERE collprovider IN ('d', 'c') AND collname NOT IN ('C', 'POSIX');
```

For the affected indices, an index rebuild can be performed with:

```
REINDEX CONCURRENTLY idx_name;
```

For me that didn't work - because of the broken index, there were duplicate keys in the table. A `SELECT` did not find all the duplicate keys. First I had to do:

```
VACUUM FULL table_name
```

Then find duplicate rows, delete them, and rebuild the indices. It may be convenient to you to use the table name instead of index name:

```
REINDEX TABLE CONCURRENTLY table_name;
```